# How to group by time-interval from bottom to top using Pandas resample functionality?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am working with historic data of some stocks. I want to group data by certain time intervals (like 1hr, 3days, etc). Pandas gives amazing functionality of doing this with very less efforts using `resampling`. But it happens from `top-to-bottom` (below image).
Like -

```
With interval = 5m

Group 1 => 9:30 - 9:35
Group 2 => 9:35 - 9:40
Group 3 => 9:40 - 9:45
```

[image]

Here, I want to group from `bottom-to-top`, like -

```
With interval = 5m

Group 1 => 9:45 - 9:40
Group 2 => 9:40 - 9:35
Group 3 => 9:35 - 9:30
```

How can I do this with pandas resampling? If there is another way of doing this please mention it as well. Thanks :)

**EDIT**:
I want something like this out of above image data -

```
5-min groups                     open    max_high     max_low       close   sum_volume
2022-05-05 09:45:00-04:00  162.750000  162.750000  162.529999  162.540100   338003
2022-05-05 09:40:00-04:00  163.000000  163.440002  163.000000  163.220001   419992 
2022-05-05 09:35:00-04:00  163.500000  163.535004  163.500000  163.535004   366042
2022-05-05 09:30:00-04:00  163.850006  163.989899  163.509995  163.649994  2720494
```

Comment: shouldn't it give you the exact same results, except maybe the group names?

Comment: `df['Date'].dt.floor('5T')`

Comment: This works like floor value for time intervals. In this case I want `groups` like pandas group_by operation groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the `iloc` to reverse after resample? I'm not sure if that hinders your further calculations, but it can resample and reverse the set.

Since I do not have access to your exact sample data

**Here's how I am testing it:**

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = yf.download(tickers = 'BTC-USD',
                   start = '2022-05-16',
                   end = '2022-05-17',
                   interval = '1m',
                   group_by = 'ticker',
                   auto_adjust = True).reset_index()

df_1min = df.iloc[110:130,:] #sample timeframe extracted
df_1min.head()
```

This results in the 1 min df:

[image: 1min df]

You can then apply `resample` and the `iloc`:

```
conversion = {'Open' : 'first', 
              'High' : 'max', 
              'Low' : 'min', 
              'Close' : 'last', 
              'Volume' : 'sum'}

df_1min = df_1min.set_index('Datetime') 

df_5min = df_1min.resample('5T').agg(conversion)

df_5min.iloc[::-1].reset_index() #reverse
```

This results in a reversed df:

[image: reversed and resampled]

Comment: Thank you sir, this exactly solves my problem :)

Comment: One thing! If our last row in `df_1min` has `Datetime = 2022-05-16 02:22:00`. We can use `offset = "22min"` in resample() which will group all dates as - `2022-05-16 02:22:00 -> 2022-05-16 02:17:00 -> 2022-05-16 02:12:00 -> ...`